Worker service not writing to event log in production environment
I'm converting a Windows Service written in C# from .NET Framework to .NET 8.0. I copied the Microsoft joke service example of hosting a worker service as a windows service and altered it to call my classes. It logs to a custom Event log, named EmailService and I have altered appSettings.json as below
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Information"
    },
    "EventLog": {
      "SourceName": "MyServices",
      "LogName": "EmailService",
      "LogLevel": {
        "Microsoft": "Information",
        "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
      }
    }
  }
}

When I run the worker service in Visual Studio it logs 'Hosting environment:Development' and writes my messages to the event log as expected. When I run it as a service or just invoke the EXE, it says 'Hosting environment: Production' and does not write to the event log except to say it is starting/stopping, what the environment is and the content root path. All of my log messages appear in the console, regardless of the environment. The bin folder contains appsettings.json, appsettings.Development.json & appsettings.Production.json - all are the same. I have tried publishing the app as a single file and tried adding
Environment.CurrentDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
to the program.cs file of the worker service as advised for a similar issue posted here, but the result is the same.
